# Problem in printing cropped pdf file

Tags: printing, pdfcrop

I am facing a problem printing a cropped pdf file. I used pdfcrop in ubuntu. The digital version looks as it should look but when I tried to print that (using adobe reader) the print out was not the cropped at all! Can someone one help me to get around this problem.

Comment: Your document is invisible to us ;-)

Comment: Sorry! Should I upload the document?

Comment: Well, you should clearify first whether this a LaTeX etc. related question at all.

Comment: Actually, no. But I saw some pdfcrop related questions in this forum. That's why I posted it here.

Comment: In Adobe Reader, make sure you are printing "fit to page" and not "actual size".

Comment: @PhysicsMoron: Well, I would say, that `pdfcrop` questions are off-topic, but apparently they were answered here anyway

Comment: @James I tried that too, but didn't work.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I agree, they are off-topic.